# Return Redshift Cluster IDs as an array - Step Functions

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am attempting to inspect my running Redshift clusters, determine if an instance of interest is up, and then take action.

I am attempting to use `$.Clusters[:].ClusterIdentifier` in my Result Selector to setup the data sent to the next state task.

- Above works when I validate against other tools (online JSON Path utilities)
- Above works when using AWS's Data Flow Simulator (Screenshot below)

[image]

However, when I put this into the Step Function and attempt to save the changes (Visual Editor), I get the following error.

[image]

What am I missing, especially since this does not fail in the Result Selector in the Data Flow Simulator?

Comment: Will mark this out when I can, but the issue is that `:` is not supported, and `*` should be used.